# Is there a good reason to initialize PHP arrays before adding variables/values to it?

Tags: php, arrays, initialization

is there any reason to initialize array like so:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = 44;
```

when

```
$arr[] = 44;
```

does the same thing?

Comment: It's more clear and if you already have an $arra[] before, your $arg[]=44 is not the first but the 2nd element.

Comment: as per the manual on arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php *An array can be created using the array() language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated key => value pairs as arguments. .* - So, if you're not planning on doing anything special with `array()`, then there's no need to declare it. There's also the fact about versions of PHP, where older versions require `array()` rather than `[]` if < 5.4.